# buster blader the dragon destroyer swoardsman effect not working

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Why doesn't buster blader the dragon destroyer swordsman with DNA surgery on the field stop destiny hero plasma's effect that allows plasma to take my monster. Oh BTW this is in the duel links game

Comment: Hey Hopey, what you are experiencing here is due to the same reason I exposed on my answer to your post I linked... thus why I casted a close vote as it is a Duplicate... this will be the case with any card that has continuous effects (that don't "activate" per se)...

Answer (score 1):

Buster bladers effect states:

```
Dragon type monsters in your opponents possession cannot activate their effects
```

Normally this would prevent Destiny hero - Plasma from activating it's absorb effect.
However, Plasma has a second effect:

```
Negate the effects of face-up monsters while your opponent controls them.
```

This is a continous effect, so it doesn't activate and so isn't blocked by Buster blader. This means that Buster bladers effect is negated and so can't stop Plasma from absorbing him.

For completions sake, in the case we have two monsters (e.g. 2 Plasma, or jinzo vs skill drain) that would negate eachothers effect. the one first on the field will win out and negate the other one.